Misc entry ouputs weird characters in front of title
I'm a beginner Overleaf user and I am using a template. The project uses the [numbers]{natbib} package and I have several online resources in my bib tex using the @misc entry:
@misc{EmotivLicense,
  title = {{Emotiv Pro Licenses}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.emotiv.com/products/emotivpro}},
  note = {Accessed: 2024-05-03}
}

but it produces this weird comma and point in front of the title:

Other online sources have lowercase letters in front:

The part in the style file responsible for the bibliography looks like this:
 {\section{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
       \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5\parsep}
       \wscgraggedright
       \setlength{\parsep}{1.0ex}
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}

An example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\title{test}
\author{xx}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{Emotiv}
\cite{CortexAPI}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}


bibtex entries:
@misc{Emotiv,
  author = {Emotiv},
  title = {Emotiv {I}nsight {P}roduct {P}age},
  url = {https://www.emotiv.com/insight/}},
  note = {Accessed: 2022-05-19}
}

@misc{CortexAPI,
  author = {Emotiv},
  title = {Cortex {API} {D}ocumentation},
  url = {https://emotiv.gitbook.io/cortex-api},
  note = {Accessed: 2022-05-19}
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I just updated the post.

If you add \raggedright before \bibliography so it is not so stretched out, and add date fields to your entries you will see

so the a and b are avoiding duplication of the empty date.
You may hope that the bst file checked for empty date and skipped the entire field, but it doesn't.
If this is for a conference or publication where this style is mandated, I would just add date fields to the entries.
Otherwise you could modify a copy  of the bst file and get
test for empty year
FUNCTION {misc}
{ "%Type = Misc" write$
  output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  year empty$
   {}
   {format.date "year" output.check}
   if$
  date.block
  format.title output
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  new.block
  print.url output
  print.doi output
  print.eprint output
  print.pubmed output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

and
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\title{test}
\author{xx}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{Emotiv}
\cite{CortexAPI}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\raggedright
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}


